# Is it possible to call classes of nested divs with JS/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to find this anywhere...Just wondering if it's possible to call nested divs and place them in one function? For example:

```
<div class="a">
<div class="b-1"></div>
<div class="b-2"></div>
</div>
```

How do I call them together as a function to update their styles?

Edit: I might not be too clear here. What I am trying to ask is... For example:

```css
.a {
background-color: black; width:200px; height: 200px; position: relative; }

.b-1 { color: white;
position: absolute;}

.b-2 {color: white;
position: absolute; padding-top: 20px; }
```

```html
<div class="a">

<div class="b-1"> test b1</div>
<div class="b-2"> test b2</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to update a, b-1, b-2 classes in one function?

So the result is:

```
function updateMultipleClasses() {
change a to grey
change b1 and b2 to red

}
```

I would like to be able to just call this function instead. is this possible?

Comment: You mean to call all the child of div with class a?

Comment: you can use `$(".a").children();` . It gives you all children of class `a`

Comment: I meant to call both a, b-1 and b-2 together and place them in a function where I can change the style?

Comment: You should really [edit] your question and be more precise about what you're after.

Comment: Only change `b-1` and `b-2` or all child of `a` class?

Comment: what if you have another tag with `b-3` class? is it important to start with `b-`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery wild card selector

```js
$("div[class^='b-']").addClass('test')
```

```css
.test {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b-1">B-1</div>
  <div class="b-2">B-2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) by using `querySelectorAll` to your function that will select both parent and all children `div` elements and then use `forEach` loop on that selector.

```js
function updateStyles(els) {
  els.forEach(e => {
    e.style.border = '1px solid red'
    
    if (e.classList.contains('a')) {
        e.style.backgroundColor = 'green'
    }
    
    if ([...e.classList].some(cls => ['b-1', 'b-2'].includes(cls))) {
        e.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
    }
    
  })
}

updateStyles(document.querySelectorAll('.a, .a div'))
```

```css
* {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b-1">1</div>
  <div class="b-2">
    <div class="b-3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To be more precise - You're not passing a *selector*, you're passing a NodeList. And NodeList provides a  [forEach prototype Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

Comment: what if i want a to be in green background colour and then b1, b2 in white when the function is called?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan True, fixed.

Comment: @bugbytes Then you cal add logic for that inside the function or you can just use two different selectors and write the code for each of them. One would be for single a element and another one for multiple b elements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JS to *style*.
Use JS only to add a class to the `.a` Element, than **use CSS** to define the styles that should be applied to the ancestor and its children.

```js
const makeSelected = (EL) => {
  EL.classList.add("selected");
};

document.querySelectorAll(".a").forEach(makeSelected);
```

```css
.a.selected {
  color: gold;
}

.a.selected [class^="b-"],
.a.selected [class*=" b-"]{
  color: fuchsia;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  a a a a a
  <div class="b-1">b 1 1 1 1</div>
  <div class="b-2">b 2 2 2 2</div>
</div>
```